# Проверка содержимого div через jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача - проверить пуст ли div ? Содержимое в div подгружается через ajax, по мимо этого есть скрипт которые при определённых условиях выводит звуковое оповещение. Собственно не могу понять как запретить скрипту запускать оповещение когда в div есть содержимое. Пытался сделать через такую конструкцию :

```
if($(".grid_call_main_orders_one_content").is(':empty')){
    var audio = new Audio(); 
    audio.src = 'alert.mp3';

    audio.autoplay = true;
   setTimeout(function () {
   alert('Новый заказ!Обновите страницу! ');
  }, 3000);
    }
```

Но схема не рабочая.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через `$('selector').text().length`;

```js
let a = $('#a').text().length;
let b = $('#b').text().length;
a > 0 ? alert ('a have value') : alert ('a empty');
b > 0 ? alert ('b have value') : alert ('b empty');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'>hi</div>
<div id='b'></div>
```

Comment: По вашему алгоритму следующий блок тоже будет считаться пустым `<div id='b'><p></p><div><span></span></div></div>`. Может, еще добавить проверку на `children`.

Answer (score 0):

В JQuery есть метод [.html()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_html-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) - он берет содержимое из элемента. 
Принцип такой, берем содержимое и проверяем его на пустоту, пример: 
**$("here").html() == "";**

```js
var contentGridBlock = $(".grid_call_main_orders_one_content");
// Кнопки для теста
$(".gridFull").click(function() {
  contentGridBlock.html("Я наполнен");
});
$(".gridClear").click(function() {
  contentGridBlock.html("");
});
$(".gridCheck").click(function() {
  // Тут самое интересное
  var checkContent = contentGridBlock.html();
  if(checkContent == "") {
    alert("Блок пустой");
  } else {
    alert("Блок с контентом");
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_call_main_orders_one_content"></div>
<button class="gridCheck">Проверка контента</button>
<button class="gridFull">Наполнить блок тестовым контентом</button>
<button class="gridClear">Удалить из блока тестовый контент</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```